# why can't I retrieve data from model without using a forloop

Tags: python, django

I shouldn't use a for loop if I have different approach right? to avoid big o(n)? so here's what I have.

models.py

```
class Drama(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    theOffice = Drama.objects.filter(name='The Office')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'theOffice':theOffice,
                })
```

and now in the template

```
{{ theOffice.name }}
```

the above displays nothing, what really bothers me is 
if I use a for loop it works,

```
{% for theOffi in theOffice %}
{{ theOffi.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But then, what's the point of using filter?I can just get objects.all() and use

```
 {% if drama.name == "the office %}
```

am I missing something? I'm really confused

Comment: filter returns a `QuerySet[]`.

Comment: The key here is understanding what the `n` is in your `O(n)`. When you loop over `objects.all()`, `n` is the total number of objects. When you loop over `objects.filter()`, `n` is the number of _matching_ objects, which is much, much smaller. (There is a cost to `filter`, of course—but unless your backend is a dumb list or equivalent, the cost is much lower than linear, so it's still a win.)

Comment: @abarnert what's the difference between filter and get in the time matter do you know? I know get only retrieve one, I want to use it but it gives me if I don't have a matching value in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter returns an array. `If you use Drama.objects.filter(name='The Office')[0]` your code will work

Comment: If you to get a single item, use `.get()` instead of `filter()` and `[0]`.

Comment: @KlausD. get is faster?

Comment: @KlausD. because it's not using a loop at all?

Comment: Yes it will be faster. But neither a loop of one item nor a `.get()` will ever reach the costs of the involved SQL query. If you want to improve performance, you have to answer different questions first.

Comment: Django query sets are lazily evaluated. Slicing the query sets performs a limit (and/or) offset on the SQL database.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Answer (score 0):

Looping over and testing all of the elements takes linear time. If you have, say, a million elements, this takes 1 million comparisons, even if only 5 of them match.

Looping over the result of `filter` does *not* take linear time.

`filter` can use the underlying database or other backend to find just the elements that match. Typically, this is in better than linear time—e.g., with a typical database, where the values are index in a b-tree with an average width of 10, it can find the 5 matches in `log(1_000_000, 10) + 5 = 11` comparisons. Which is a whole lot better than 1 million.

Since there could be 5 matches—or 0, or 20—you still get back a `QuerySet`—an iterable that you have to loop over. But you're only looping over the 5 matches, not the 1 million elements, so your total complexity is `11 + 5 = 16`, which is still a whole lot better than 1 million.

---

If you know for a fact that there will always be exactly 1 match, you don't even need to loop over them; just use the first one with `Drama.objects.filter(name='The Office')[0]`. Then, the search takes 6 comparisons.

Compared to `6 + 1 = 7` steps with a loop, this 6 steps isn't much of an optimization. But that's not why you do it; you do it for simplicity and correctness:

- You know there will be exactly one value, so you make that explicit in your code, and then it's obvious to any reader.
- Your code is shorter and simpler to read.
- If you were wrong, and there are actually sometimes no matches, you get an exception instead of no output, which is easier to debug.